# always getting this error when deletion performed

Tags: mysql

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Lock ' at line 171"

I think it's because 'Lock' is a reserved word but i am using it in my table.

so how to overcome this issue.

Comment: delete from TABLENAME where CONDITION

Comment: Be specific to understand the actual problem. Add whole query and complete error

Answer (score 2):

Use back ticks to quote the reserved words.

```
`lock`
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use **back tick character** for reserved word

You need to use reserved word as `'Lock'`

(Source: [MySQL Reference Manual, 9.3 Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reserved-words.html))